# Mysql joints is possible?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have two table one table containing station id and station name, and another table containing id, name, startStationId, endStationId. I know second table's id by using that id i need to fetch all details of second table with station name for corresponding startStationId, endStationId.

```
ex: table1
---------------------------------
slNo staionId staionName
---------------------------------
1     0012     Bangalore ,
2     0014     Chennai ,
3     0015     Mumbai
---------------------------------

Table 2:
------------------------------------------
Id   Name    startStationId   endStationId
-------------------------------------------
123  Dhinesh   0014             0015
-------------------------------------------
```

For example i know second table id(123).. so i want to fetch all results by using id, result would be.

Id =>123, Name => Dhinesh, StartStaion =>Chennai , Endstation=>Mumbai.

How can we write in one single query...?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT t2.Id,t2.name,t1.StationName,t3.StationName
FROM table2 t2
INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON t2.startStationId = t1.stationId
INNER JOIN table1 t3 ON t2.endStationId = t3.stationId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t2.Id, t2.Name, tstart.stationName , tend.stationName 
FROM table2 as t2 
INNER JOIN table1 as tstart  ON t2.startStationId =  tstart.stationId
INNER JOIN table1 as tend  ON t2.endStationId = tend.stationId
```

this should work